# Load XML for each request 

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

My application loads a xml and update xml elements for each request.

I have 10 to 20 requests come at a time , the xml loading process is taking some time for each request because it is in synchronized block.

The xml size is 500 KB and used DOM parser (Legacy code).

Are there any ways to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced DOM parser with Stax parser. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your application, other consumers of the XML data, or the control you have over your environment, you might consider keeping the data on the application server (is it the same file or a bunch of different files, each 500kb?) and running a periodic copy job to send an updated copy back to the original source at a reasonable interval.

Comment: merging might be difficult if there is more than one application server (or other writers).

Comment: The XML resides on the same machine/server

Comment: Okay, but to be clear, the original question DID say that the files were on a different machine. What we still haven't heard is whether we're dealing with one XML file or if all of these 20-30 simultaneous requests are working with different XML files.

Answer (score 1):

> *I have replaced DOM parser with Stax parser. Solved my issue.*

[VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) is faster and memory-efficienter. However... I highly question the **need** to parse the XML file on *every* request. Caching it in application scope using a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and saving the cached content every minute or so using a [`TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) would be more efficient.